# Move ERC20 tokens from Ethereum Wallet Contract to Account

Tags: erc-20, myetherwallet, access, wallet-contracts

In my Ethereum wallet, I am trying to access my wallet conract. If I sync in light mode and import the wallet contract address it just stays there displayed, greyed out and nothing happens, no matter which Ethereum wallet/geth version combination I try.

Or if I download the full blockchain it stops short at the last 100 blocks and never fully syncs.

Basically, my wallet contact doesn't show up in any case :(

It contains all my ERC20 tokens and I can't access them.

I have tried many combinations of Geth and Ethereum wallet versions to get the desired effect but to no use. Apparently, this wallet import issue will be fixed in 0.12 but I can't wait that long.

Is there a way to use MEW to do this or some other online wallet?

Thanks in advance

Peter

Answer (score 0):

What method do you use for accessing your funds? Keystore file, private key string, mnemonic phrase, or hardware wallet? The tokens will always exist on the blockchain associated with your private key until you are able to access them.

You can probably get this working on the MyCrypto desktop app.

1. Download and install the app from https://download.mycrypto.com
2. Open the app and access your wallet using the method you have access to your ERC20 tokens on.
3. On the right-hand side of the app there is a "scan for tokens" option. If we have the token listed in our open-source repo (https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens) then it should show up there. If not, you'll have to add your tokens as custom tokens. Here is the documentation for how to do that: https://support.mycrypto.com/tokens/adding-new-token-and-sending-custom-tokens.html
4. TLDR: You'll need the contract address and number of decimals that the contract uses (18, 12, 9, 6, or 3 normally). Input them into the "Add Custom Token" prompt and submit it. Then you should see the tokens that you have for that contract address.

You can transfer them away if you need to, or just leave them there knowing that they're safe and sound. Feel free to message our support through the link at the bottom of that knowledge-base article if you need any further help. Best of luck!

Comment: Hello, I access my ERC20 tokens by opening my Ethereum wallet and clicking on the wallet contract (an extra layer of security). To withdraw tokens from this wallet contract, Ethereum wallet requires me to enter a password to enable the transaction to take place. Essentailly, I only have the address and password for the wallet contract, there is no such private key associated with it. Is there such functionality where I can submit the JSON file to access the account, BUT MORE IMPORTANTLY to import the wallet contract and withdraw from it using this password?

Comment: When I say Ethereum wallet I mean the desktop wallet created by the Ethereum foundation. Thanks so far for your help, if you can enable me to access my tokens I will send you some ETH as a token of my appreciation! :)

Comment: Also when I say "there is no such private key associated with it" I mean there is no private key I can copy & paste, just the JSON file for the Account which owns the wallet contract and the password I have memorised.